# script from python 3.5 to 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, py2exe

## Context

I am busy making a game using pygame on python 3.5 but when i wanted to link the game to my friends I realized i needed a .exe file because they dont have python installed so I did some research and found out that you can use py2exe for that. But after looking on the downloads page I saw that there was no download for python 3.5.

## Question

Can i still use another version of py2exe to convert my .py and my modules to a .exe file or do I need to have python 2.7 (or any other python version which is compatible).
If i do need another version is there an easy way to convert my 3.5 script to a 2.7 script or do i need to write it all over?

I hope I have given you all the info you need. But feel free to ask if you need more.

Comment: python 3.5 is very similar to 2.7 - maybe it will work without modifications.

Comment: Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 differ a lot. You you try [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I've had great luck with pyinstaller: http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: Try to execute the script with python2.7 and see if it throws errors. Not much is different between python 2.7 and python 3.5 but there ARE differences and they are big ones too. Some standard libraries in 3.5 might be third-party libs in 2.7, the syntax differs sublty here and there. So you dont need to write the script from scratch, you need to modify it for 2.7. Even better you can do lot of wrestling and make it compatible with both 2.7 and 3.5 but your code might look ugly especially in the `import` statements.